# How to prevent form submit when using Bootstrap file input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I'm using [this](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo) the Bootstrap function to upload images. The example I'm following is the number 1.

I added the `data-` attributes for validating the images uploaded (for example if the image selected exceded the height allowed).

```
<form:input ...
     type="file"        
     cssClass="file"        
     data-show-upload="false"
     data-show-caption="true"
     data-max-image-height="800"
     data-msg-image-height-large="Error"
     />
```

Everything works good, if an error is detected the error is shown on the page, as you can see here:[image]

Now, my question is: how can I prevent the submit of the form if there are errors on my input file fields?

I tried something like the code below, but the validator seems not to recognize that there are errors on the input file fields. 
**IMPORTANT:** the validator recognizes other "boostrap" error like `data-minlength` and prevent correctly the submit of the form

```
('.myForm').validator().on('submit', function (e) {     
      // ERROR
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) { 
         alert("Error");             
      }
      // NO ERROR
      else {             
          alert("NO Error");                
      }
    })
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle or something? is there any callback you can get if there's an error?

Comment: I expected bootStrap itself "gives" me a callbak in case of error, but I didn't find it on the documentation. Probably I miss something

Comment: As you are using that plugin, that plugin should give callback in that case. Its not a default Bootstrap functionality.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I'll check documentation again. Thank you